# I want to send a mail to specific user with dummy mail id which do not exist using smtp library in python

Tags: python

I am trying to send mail to specific user with dummy mail id using local host.
I ran the below sample code

```
import smtplib

SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = "foo@bar.com"

TO = ['mygmail@gmail.com']

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "Test mail"

message = """\

From: %s
To : %s
Subject : %s

%s
""" % (FROM,", ".join(TO), SUBJECT , TEXT)

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)

server.sendmail(FROM,TO,message)

server.quit()
```

After running the code i am getting below eror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\Timesheet\mail_list.py", line 20, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: `SERVER = "localhost"` → is your local machine a mail server? https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-your-own-email-server/

Comment: no i have not set local machine as a mail server.

Comment: So, that is the problem. Choose proper smtp server